# Using back on ajax pages

Tags: jquery, back, forward

I don't use hashes so forget about the hashchange things. (using "/" and then only in some extra menus "#"-s)

Can't I just make a function something like:

```
"whenbackbuttonisclicked" function(){
history.back();
}
```

and the same for forward?

Comment: Data loaded with ajax isn't saved when you use history.back().

Comment: try this if it works for you? https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: The page is actually 1 file and just switching div-s, I couldn't get pjax to work unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something with the onpopstate event, and potentially editing the history object to remove the page change.  You will want to do some research into how different browsers handle this event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate

There are quite a few StackOverflow questions related to popstate - that might be a good place to begin your research.